# How do I limit a grep command in UNIX to a specific file and a specific directory in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm trying to use the grep command to find a unique string in each line of a file containing thousands of lines in a specific directory and save the output in a single line in a new file(e.g. output.txt). I then repeat the process for many more files storing all output in the same file.

However, the output for each line using the grep command far exceeds the total number of lines in each file, and the output also contains results for only one file instead of many more hundreds. Furthermore, in order not to alter any of the files in the directory, I copied the directory to another location in order to protect the original. Below is the code (with comments) I wrote for your viewing and help;

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a genomes < list.txt
j=0
m=0
grep -o Eco.* ./${genomes[j]}_ani_output.txt | cut -c 59- | cut -d '/' -f 1 >> list1
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a genome_names < list1 
rm list1

while [ $m -eq 0 ] 
do
    for((i=0; i<=16547; i++))
    do
        grep -w ${genome_names[i]} ./${genomes[j]}_ani_output.txt >> list2 # grep command to fine unique genome names in a specific order. This grep command in the for loop is the problem. generates wrong outputs
    done

    if ((i=16547))
    then      
        cut -f 3 list2 >> list3
        rm list2                    

        IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a values < list3 
        echo "${genomes[j]} ${values[*]}" >> table
        i=$((i-i))            
        j=$((j+1))              
        rm list3
        unset name 
    fi

    if ((j=1000))
    then
        m=$((m+1))
    fi
done
```

The first cut command is used to get the genome name in the second column of the file named list1 as can be seen in the attached image. The second cut is used to get the values of each genome. The number 16547 is the total number of lines found in each file.

[content of file with unique genome names in second column retrieved using first cut command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9unyd.png)

Comment: Which is the _unique string_? What's the use of the `cut` commands in your script? What's that number _16547_? Can you guarantee that there's no problem before the place where you write `This grep command in the for loop is the problem`? - Sample data would help to figure out what should go on.

Comment: And are you sure that the files `list1`, `list2` and `list3` don't exist when you run the script?

Comment: You lost me on the 16547 constant. I think you could replace the `for((i=0; i<=16547; i++))` by `for((i=0; i<=${#genome_names[@]}; i++))` to ensure you parse exactly the right number of genomes, no matter how much you caught during the previous step.

Comment: comment says - `grep -w ${genome_names[i]} ./${genomes[j]}_ani_output.txt >> list2` - generates the wrong output; the rest of the script is of little use; I'd rewrite the entire question to focus on this `grep` command ... provide the contents of `${genome_names[@]}"` (eg, first 5 entries), sample set of data from `${genomes[1]}_ani_output.txt` (10-20 lines, some that match the 5 sample genome names), the 'wrong output' generated by the `grep` and the (correct) expected output you want

Comment: also, with regards to the comment - `# grep command to fine unique genome names in a specific order` - there is nothing about this `grep` command that provides 'unique' or 'ordered' data so if you could provide more details on what you think this `grep` is supposed to be doing would be helpful

Comment: Sure Armali, there is no problem before the place where I write the comment, and yes the files list1, list2 and list3 don't exist when I run the script.

Comment: I would love to share an output but its huge even just for one line. The problem with the for loop is that it works in some way for smaller values of 'i' e.g. 100, but with increasing numbers of about 700, it generates thousands  of lines of output in the file named 'list2' instead of the 700 specified. And after the first iteration in the for loop it stops and doesn't move on to another file as intended inside the for loop.

Comment: Unrelated, but consider using `readarray -t genomes < list.txt` instead of `read`.

Comment: What about using AG, faster than grep, and made for your kind of queries: https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher